# Unable to resolve "firebase/app" from "screens\LoginScreen.js"

Tags: javascript, firebase-authentication, expo, react-native-firebase, expo-go

I have a `firebase.js` file containing the Firebase configuration with the code provided below. I also have a `RegistrationScreen.js` file containing the following code:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { View, TextInput, TouchableOpacity, Text, StyleSheet, ScrollView } from 'react-native';
import { auth } from '../firebase';

const RegistrationForm = () => {
  const [surname, setSurname] = useState('');
  const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const [confirmPassword, setConfirmPassword] = useState('');
  const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState('');

  const handleRegistration = async () => {
    // Check if all fields are filled
    if (!firstName || !surname || !email || !password || !confirmPassword) {
      console.log('Please fill in all fields');
      return;
    }

    // Check if email is valid
    const emailRegex = /^[^\s@]+@[^\s@]+\.[^\s@]+$/;
    if (!emailRegex.test(email)) {
      console.log('Please enter a valid email address');
      return;
    }

    // Check if password and confirm password match
    if (password !== confirmPassword) {
      console.log('Passwords do not match');
      return;
    }

    // Check if password meets the required criteria
    const passwordRegex = /^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*]).{8,}$/;
    if (!passwordRegex.test(password)) {
      console.log(
        'Password must be at least 8 characters long, contain at least one uppercase letter, one lowercase letter, one special character, and one number'
      );
      return;
    }

    try {
      // Check if email already exists
      await checkEmailExists(email);

      console.log('Registration successful');
      // Add any additional logic you want to perform after successful registration

      auth
        .registerUser(surname, firstName, email, username)
        .then((usercredentials) => {
          const user = usercredentials.user;
          console.log(user.email);
        })
        .catch((error) => alert(error.message));
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={styles.scrollContainer} showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}>
        <Text style={styles.heading}>Create Account</Text>
        <View style={styles.formContainer}>
          <TextInput style={styles.input} placeholder="First Name" value={firstName} onChangeText={setFirstName} />
          <TextInput style={styles.input} placeholder="Surname" value={surname} onChangeText={setSurname} />
          <TextInput style={styles.input} placeholder="Email" value={email} onChangeText={setEmail} />
          <TextInput style={styles.input} placeholder="Username" value={username} onChangeText={setUsername} />
          <TextInput
            style={styles.input}
            placeholder="Password"
            secureTextEntry
            value={password}
            onChangeText={setPassword}
          />
          <TextInput
            style={styles.input}
            placeholder="Confirm Password"
            secureTextEntry
            value={confirmPassword}
            onChangeText={setConfirmPassword}
          />
          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={handleRegistration}>
            <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Register</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  scrollContainer: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    paddingBottom: 16,
  },
  formContainer: {
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  heading: {
    fontSize: 24,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    color: 'black',
    marginBottom: 30,
  },
  input: {
    width: 250,
    marginBottom: 12,
    padding: 8,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: 'green',
    borderRadius: 40,
  },
  button: {
    width: 150,
    padding: 8,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: 'green',
    borderRadius: 40,
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  buttonText: {
    color: 'green',
    fontSize: 16,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
});

export default RegistrationForm;
```

How can I integrate the Firebase configuration into the `RegistrationScreen.js` file to allow users to register in my app?

the thing is when ever i run npx expo start and scan the project , i get this errors , and i have tried reinstaliing firebase but no change
the error is as follows

Logs for your project will appear below. Press Ctrl+C to exit.
Android Bundling failed 4405ms
Unable to resolve "firebase/app" from "screens\LoginScreen.js"